# Java eclipse String Error

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I'm New to Java and I am following some instruction, However When I get to the Strings section

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.lang.String name;
        name = "luke";
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "pleased to meet you");
    }
}
```

But I Get

```
Error: Main method not found in class String, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you insist on using String as your class name it should be:

```
public class String {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        java.lang.String name;
        name = "luke";
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "pleased to meet you");
    }
}
```

I don't think it's particularly wise to try and re-use the names of classes defined in `java.lang` though.

Answer (score 5):

Since your class is named String, it is being inferred by the compiler as the argument type of your main method.

Try fully qualifying the argument type instead:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
...
```

Or better yet, rename your class to use and non-java.lang class name.

Answer (score 5):

You were careful to fully-qualify your reference to `java.lang.String` for the `name` variable, but not for the `args` parameter to `main`.

Use

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

Of course, this all resulted because you named your class `String`, the same name as a built-in class in Java.  Perhaps you could name it `StringTest` instead?  That would avoid having to worry about class name collision and fully qualifying the Java built-in `String`.

Answer (score 2):

As your class hides the `java.lang.String` name, you need to write

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

Better call your class `StringTest` or something else to avoid this confusion.

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "luke";
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "pleased to meet you");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this

```
public class StringFirstTry {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    name = "luke";
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "pleased to meet you");
}
```

}